# Scikit-Learn - How to get non-normalized importance score from RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I would like to get the non-normalized importance score from RandomForestRegressor.

After fitting the regressor I can access to `feature_importances_` which contain normalized importance score.

To get non normalized score I tried this, but it didn't work. I can't get correct values:

```
arr = []
for i in range(0,len(clf.feature_importances_)):
  arr.append(np.array(clf.feature_importances_)[0:i].sum())

non_normalized = clf.feature_importances_*arr
```

Is there an option to disable the normalization?

Answer (score 1):

The importance is always normalized to sum up to 1, even when you go down to each decision tree regressor, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

boston = load_boston()

X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
y = boston.target

X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You can see within each tree, the importance values are already normalized:

```
[x.feature_importances_.sum() for x in rf.estimators_]
 
[1.0,
0.9999999999999999,
 1.0,
 1.0,
 0.9999999999999999,
 1.0,
 0.9999999999999998,...
```

Not so trivial to pull out the decrease in mse for tree and recalculate. One alternative solution would be to use `permutation_importance` with r squared or rmse as the measure, to get an estimate of how important each feature would be, these values are not normalized:

```
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
importance_r2 = permutation_importance(rf, X_test, y_test,scoring="r2")
importance_rmse = permutation_importance(rf, X_test,
 y_test,scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error")
```

And plotting the results:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
ax1.boxplot(importance_r2.importances.T, vert=False,labels=X_test.columns)
ax1.set_xlabel('Decrease in R2')
ax2.boxplot(importance_rmse.importances.T, vert=False,labels=X_test.columns)
ax2.set_xlabel('Decrease in RMSE')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the random forest is an ensemble method based on decision tree, you can access the underlying decision trees with the attribute `clf.estimators_` of the RandomForestRegressor. With the list of trees, you can have access to the feature importance of each decision tree :

```py
feat_imp = [tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf.estimators_]
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I need also the OOB when bootstrap in TRUE and it seem's OOB for each tree is not available ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the importances are normalized to sum to 1. However, one can change that by accessing the trees of a random forest or a decision tree model and calling the function to compute importances with `normalize=False`.

First here is an example with a single decision tree regression:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn import tree

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
model = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)
model.fit(X,y)
model.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=False)
```

```
array([ 273.29445957,   55.8130721 , 1383.95383906,  447.64458872,
        414.2412427 ,  412.20392795,  423.76003212,   77.75521807,
       2063.37527614,  377.84324049])
```

For the random forest there is an extra step. We need to first access each tree, compute the feature importances per tree and then perform the average across trees:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0)
model.fit(X,y)

importances = np.zeros((model.n_estimators, model.n_features_))
for i,tree in enumerate(model.estimators_):
    importances[i] = tree.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=False)
np.mean(importances, axis=0)
```

```
array([ 363.40653952,   78.42318883, 1767.47349563,  564.32760593,
        275.84188613,  318.61079764,  310.57670354,  160.56454205,
       1655.62870107,  424.28382897])
```